# React.js Redux: unwanted change of redux store on input handling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I use `mapStateToProps` to map some value from the redux store to props:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    // state.layers has 3 Objects containing arrays
    return {
        layers: state.availableLayers.toObject()
    };
}
```

I am displaying the different layers and the user can chose the one he/she wants to create. On click event I write the chosen layer to state:

```
openParams(layer){
    this.setState({
        showLayer: layer
    });
}
```

The argument for the layer is passed from a click event where I iterate through all the posible layers in `this.props.layers`.

Now I want the user to be able to change some config. For that I have a handleInput event whenever the input of a config field changes:

```
handleChange(e) {
    let field = e.target.name;
    let value = e.target.value;

    let tmpLayer= this.state.showLayer;
    tmpLayer[field]["value"] = value;

    this.setState({ showLayer: tmpLayer });
}
```

When the user is done I call the redux action: `this.props.actions.createLayer(this.state.showLayer);`

But when I do that, the store does not only create the layer. But also changes the state.availableLayers in the redux store. But that data should stay untouched. My reducer does not change it, I already checked that. It seems like the line `tmpLayer[field]["value"] = value;` is changing the redux store. But I don't understand why? It seems like there is some reference from my `this.state.showLayer` to the redux store?! I already tried to copy the object on `mapStateToProps` with immutable.js and with `Object.assign({}, state.availableLayer.toObject()`, but it didn't help.

EDIT: using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.showLayer))` resolves the issue while `Object.assign({}, this.state.showLayer)` and `{...this.state.showLayer}` suggested by @mkatanski do not. How that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright. There is a reference into the store and to change that a deep copy is needed as the strucutre and fields of `showLayer` are not known beforehand and can vary depending the type of layer.

Using either this `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.showLayer))` in the `handleChange()`function or `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.availableLayers.toObject))` in `mapStateToProps()` resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the spread operator, for example:

```
const tmpLayer = {
 ...this.state.showLayer
}
```

This is recommended way of doing clone without reference by [redux documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/recipes/UsingObjectSpreadOperator.md).

Also, you can try to use immutability helpers from react addons: 
[React: Immutability Helpers](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html)

EDIT:

If none of above work, you can also do it manually:

```
const tmpLayer = {}
Object.keys(showLayer).forEach(elem => {
   tmpLayer[elem] = showLayer[elem]
})
```

Comment: I tried your first suggestion. It does not resolve the issue. `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.showLayer))` seems to work on the other hand... but what I have read it is quite expensive.

Comment: That is strange. Maybe doing a method which manualy copies object elements would be better? I think faster than `JSON` aproach. See my edit.

Comment: Its becaues it only clones the first level. And [field][value] is the second level. Since I have different data structures and don't know the fields in advance I need a deep copy.

Comment: Yeah, it also only copys the first level of the object. If you do something like that: `l.deep.deepTest = 'change Deep'`, both objects in your example change. https://jsfiddle.net/g8jea0e5/1/